# Find Virtual Network Interfaces in C (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, driver, ioctl

I try to find a way, in C code, to distinguish whether a network interface is virtual or physical.

I was thinking to check whether the network interface is mapped to a driver, assuming that if there is no driver, it is most likely a virtual adapter (is there a more relevant method?).

**Example (on a physical adapter):**

```sh
$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: e1000
....
```

**Example (on a virtual adapter):**

```sh
$ ethtool -i eth10
Cannot get driver information: Operation not supported
```

Naturally, I looked at the source of ethtool to understand how it accesses the driver info: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/core/ethtool.c

Here's the part that interests us:

```c
static noinline_for_stack int ethtool_get_drvinfo(struct net_device *dev,
                          void __user *useraddr)
{
    struct ethtool_drvinfo info;
    const struct ethtool_ops *ops = dev->ethtool_ops;

    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
    info.cmd = ETHTOOL_GDRVINFO;
    if (ops->get_drvinfo) {
        ops->get_drvinfo(dev, &info);
    } else if (dev->dev.parent && dev->dev.parent->driver) {
        strlcpy(info.bus_info, dev_name(dev->dev.parent),
            sizeof(info.bus_info));
        strlcpy(info.driver, dev->dev.parent->driver->name,
            sizeof(info.driver));
    } else {
        return -EOPNOTSUPP;
        }
        ...
}
```

To get the net_device, there is a call to *__dev_get_by_name(net, ifr->ifr_name)*, this function is apparently defined in

Problem is that __dev_get_by_name() and the required structures are defined in kernel files which I am not sure I can access from an external program.

Besides when I try to include headers such as , I get tons of redefinition of structures already defined in ...

I was wondering if there is a better way to get the driver info having a **ifreq** structure (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html).

Comment: ethtool is user space utility. https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool/+/refs/heads/master/ethtool.c#1913

Comment: You are looking at the kernel source. Ethtool is a userland program. The kernel having a file named ethtool.c is of no relevance here.

Answer (score 0):

ifreq structure is mostly a compatibility thing, as the new API in Linux is rtnetlink, but I do not recommend exploring it, unless you really have to. The `ip` shell utility gives access to more or less the entire stable part of the API, but I do not think it can show you the hardware device that is responsible for the device.

But:
I would have checked  /sys/class/net/DEVICE_NAME/device symlink (is it present?)